# Efficient way of comparing multiple lists in python

Tags: python

I have 5 long lists with word pairs as given in the example below. Note that this could include word pair lists like `[['Salad', 'Fat']]` AND word pair list of lists like `[['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', ' Salt']]`

```
list_1 = [ [['Salad', 'Fat']], [['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', 'Salt']], [['Salt', 'Sugar'] ]
list_2 = [ [['Salad', 'Fat'], ['Salt', 'Sugar']], [['Protein', 'Soup']] ]
list_3 = [ [['Salad', ' Protein']], [['Bread', ' Oil']], [['Sugar', 'Salt'] ]
list_4 = [ [['Salad', ' Fat'], ['Salad', 'Chicken']] ]
list_5 = [ ['Sugar', 'Protein'], ['Sugar', 'Bread'] ]
```

Now I want to calculate the frequency of word pairs.

For example, in the above 5 lists, I should get the output as follows, where the word pairs and its frequency is shown.

```
output_list = [{'['Salad', 'Fat']': 3}, {['Bread', 'Oil']: 2}, {['Salt', 'Sugar']: 2, 
{['Sugar','Salt']: 1} and so on]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing it in python?

Comment: Is there different nesting levels of pairs within the outer list?

Comment: The most efficient way of doing it is probably to do a better job of building the original lists, so they don't have a mish-mash of various levels of nesting lists. Can you show us how they were built?

Comment: You can't use mutable objects as dictionary keys

Comment: Any reason `list_5` is only 2 levels deep, but every other list is 3 levels?

Comment: @AChampion The length of the lists vary according to my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have uneven nested lists this makes the code ugly, so would look to fix the input lists.

`collections.Counter()` is built for this kind of thing but `list`s are not hashable so you need to turn them into `tuple`s (as well as `strip` off the spurious spaces):

```
In []:
import itertools as it
from collections import Counter

list_1 = [ [['Salad', 'Fat']], [['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', 'Salt']], [['Salt', 'Sugar'] ]]
list_2 = [ [['Salad', 'Fat'], ['Salt', 'Sugar']], [['Protein', 'Soup']] ]
list_3 = [ [['Salad', ' Protein']], [['Bread', ' Oil']], [['Sugar', 'Salt'] ]]
list_4 = [ [['Salad', ' Fat'], ['Salad', 'Chicken']] ]
list_5 = [ ['Sugar', 'Protein'], ['Sugar', 'Bread']] 

t = lambda x: tuple(map(str.strip, x))
c = Counter(map(t, it.chain.from_iterable(it.chain(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4))))
c += Counter(map(t, list_5))
c

Out[]:
Counter({('Bread', 'Oil'): 2,
         ('Bread', 'Salt'): 1,
         ('Protein', 'Soup'): 1,
         ('Salad', 'Chicken'): 1,
         ('Salad', 'Fat'): 3,
         ('Salad', 'Protein'): 1,
         ('Salt', 'Sugar'): 2,
         ('Sugar', 'Bread'): 1,
         ('Sugar', 'Protein'): 1,
         ('Sugar', 'Salt'): 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However what is `it` in your code? Do we have to import it?

Comment: I think it is `import itertools as it`

Comment: Sorry, yes it is, thanks @Volka. I use it so often it is almost subconscious, `itertools as it`, `functools as ft`, `operator as op` and the other well established `numpy as np`, `pandas as pd`.

Answer (score 1):

You could [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) all the lists. Then use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to count the word frequencies.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[3,4,1,5]]
>>> counts = Counter(list(itertools.chain(*l)))
>>> counts
Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

NOTE: this flattening technique will work only with lists of lists. For other flattening techniques see the link provided above.

EDIT:
Thanks to AChampion `counts = Counter(list(itertools.chain(*l)))` can be written as `counts = Counter(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)))`

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)` would be better than arg unpacking.

Comment: Do you say this because it would be more explicit? @AChampion

Comment: It's also quicker, and built for the job.